# Using input type="file" with ASP.Net and iPad and IIS's Windows Integrated Authentication

Tags: ios, asp.net, ipad, iis, windows-authentication

I'm trying to do a really basic, no-frills file upload on a boring old HTML page using `input type="file"` that posts to an .aspx page, both hosted on IIS (both IIS7 and IIS8) with Windows Integrated Authentication enabled (not anonymous). It works just fine on Chrome for desktop, but if I use either Chrome or Safari on iPad, I can sign in (to get past Windows Auth) and see the form, but if I pick a file and click Send, it just sits and spins. If I *don't* pick a file, it works fine. If I switch from Windows Auth to Anonymous Auth, it works fine, even on the iPad. The file I'm picking is just from the iPad's photo library (originally taken with the built-in camera), and when testing Chrome for desktop, I'm testing with the exact same file (which is tiny, 1.4M).

Here's the default.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.aspx">
    <input type="file" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`upload.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="UploadTest.Upload" %>
```

`upload.aspx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace UploadTest
{
    public partial class Upload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            this.Response.Write("Got here");
            this.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I don't even try to access `this.Request.Files` in the above, although if I do, for instance:

```
var file = this.Request.Files["foo"];
this.Response.Write("Filename: " + (file == null ? "(no file)" : file.FileName));
```

...I do see the filename in the cases where it works.

I don't have a `Web.config`: I just copied `bin`, `default.html`, and `upload.aspx` into a `test` directory under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and then used IIS Manager to convert that to an application with default settings, and switch from Anonymous Auth to Windows Auth. (But this is an MCVE of a much more complex project that did have a Web.config, I've just been stripping things back to the bone to find the problem.)

To recap:

- Works just fine in Chrome on desktop
- Works just fine on iPad if I don't pick a file
- Works just fine on iPad if I switch to Anonymous Auth instead of Windows Auth and *do* pick a file
- Spins forever on iPad if I'm using Windows Auth and pick a file using either Chrome or Safari for iPad

I'm not a big ASP.net guy. What am I doing wrong? Some config switch I need to flip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is a bug in iOS (!), and it's fixed in iOS 11.0. The exact same configuration that doesn't work with v10.3 works with v11.

Unfortunately, [iOS 11.0 will only be made available for 5th gen onward](https://support.apple.com/en-us/KM207938), so we've had to work around this by reading the file via the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and sending it in batches to the server as non-file data. **Ugly** workaround, but it was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Do you remember the topic (URL or post) from Apple which said the issue was fixed in iOS 11.0? :D

Comment: @PhucNguyen: I only ever proved it experimentally: My test iPad (and more importantly, my clients' iPads) replicated the problem reliably on v10.3 (in both Safari and Chrome), then mine didn't after the upgrade to v11. Then I replicated the problem on a test iPhone running v10.3 using the exact same page that worked on the v11 iPad.

Comment: For get my question. My client upgraded their devices to iOS v11.2.5 and the issue went away. So, my ticket was solved. Thanks for you information

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using the Kerberos Security Authentication Protocol rather than NTLM protocol and uploads started working for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me (I used IIS Manager to click Authentication and pick "Negotiate:Kerberos" from the list, disabling kernel-mode authentication since it's not compatible with it). Did you do something different? Details of what you did would make the answer much more useful.